# messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp calling multiple times

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when i click on  a notification , messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp function calling multiple times

```
useEffect(() => {
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMessage => {
  if (remoteMessage) {
    const notification = 
      JSON.parse(String(remoteMessage.data));
      const notificationData = NotificationMapper([notification]);
      await notificationNavigation(notificationData[0]);
  }
})}, []);
```

this is my code ,please help me out to prevent calling above function multiple times

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the listener remover when your component gets unmounted

```
useEffect(() => {
  // assign the listener to a variable
  const listener = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMessage => {
    if (remoteMessage) {
      const notification = JSON.parse(String(remoteMessage.data));
      const notificationData = NotificationMapper([notification]);
      await notificationNavigation(notificationData[0]);
    }
  })

  // and remove it when your component gets unmounted
  return () => listener()
}, []);
```